# Circular Singly Linked List: Remove a particular Node from List

Tags: c++, list

I wrote the code to remove a particular node from list according to user
choice, code works perfectly fine for a particular value but if i make
several calls to it meaning if I call it 2 times continuously then one of my
another function `pointer_to_node(index)` gives an out of bounds error which
was also implemented by me to record such conditions,

Actually, why I need several calls is that I have to write a separate function
to remove all the nodes. I am trying to accomplish that task using this
function by using a `for` loop up to the size of my Circular Singly Linked list.
But in that case it also returns me a `NULL` pointer and gives me out of bounds
message (implemented by me in code). I have included both my functions down
here

```
void remove_from_index(int index){
  Node*temptr;
  temptr = new Node;
  int tempdata;

  if (index==1)//means remove from first
  {
    temptr = firstptr;
    tempdata= temptr->data;
    firstptr = firstptr->nextptr;
    lastptr->nextptr=firstptr;
    delete(temptr);
  } else if(index==size_of_list()) //means last node
  {
    temptr = pointer_to_node(index);
    index--; //get pointer of 2nd last position
    lastptr = pointer_to_node(index);//setting 2nd last as last postion
    temptr->nextptr=NULL;
    temptr=NULL;
    lastptr->nextptr=firstptr;
    delete (temptr);
  } else  // any position of node
  {
    temptr = pointer_to_node(index);
    tempdata = temptr->data;
    index--; // to get address of back

    Node* temp2ptr;
    temp2ptr = new Node;

    temp2ptr = pointer_to_node(index);

    index = index+2;

    Node* temp3ptr;
    temp3ptr = new Node;

    temp3ptr = pointer_to_node(index);

    temp2ptr->nextptr = temp3ptr;

    temptr->nextptr=NULL;
    delete (temptr);
  }
}


Node* pointer_to_node(int index){
  Node*temptr;
  temptr = new Node;
  temptr = firstptr;

  Node*temptr2;
  temptr2 = new Node;
  temptr2 = NULL;
  int count = 1;

  while (temptr!=temptr2){
    if (count==index)
    {
      return temptr;
    }

    count++;
    temptr2=firstptr;
    temptr=temptr->nextptr;
  }

  if (index>size_of_list())
  {
    temptr=NULL;
    cout<< "Can't You think in bounds. Take your NULL Pointer ";
    return temptr;
    delete temptr;
    delete temptr2;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of memory leaks, but overall the linkage must work. Can you please share the desctuctor of `Node` if you have declared such?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev No i have not included the destructor,,.... How can i avoid memory leaks... 

actually if i dont use     new    how should i remove the node then ?

Comment: I will add a partial answer pointing the places you have memory leaks and how you can fix that.

Comment: You didn't take the advice from your previous question about not randomly new'ing nodes and then throwing pointers away.

Comment: @JasonD actually my programming teacher says me that you should add using    new    what shoudl i do then ???? 

and i have to delete pointer at end because this is what he has taught me  :P

Comment: You add new elements with `new`. You delete with `delete`. However, when you are not adding - do not `new`. Also take care what exactly you `delete`. See first part of my answer.

Comment: Consider all the edge cases your code might have to deal with. For example what will happen if you only have one thing in your list, and you remove it?

Comment: also... how is size_of_list() implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You have several memory leaks:

```
temptr->nextptr=NULL;
temptr=NULL; // BAD!! BAD!! Remove it otherwise you will not actually free
lastptr->nextptr=firstptr;
delete (temptr);
```

And here too (actually you have this in four places of the code):

```
Node* temp2ptr;
temp2ptr = new Node; // BADD!! Why do you allocate if you are going to reassign?
temp2ptr = pointer_to_node(index);
```

Remove the bads and you will avoid the memory leaks.

Still, this is not going to fix your problem.

Also you have operations after return here:

```
return temptr;
delete temptr;
delete temptr2;
```

These are never going to be executed.

**EDIT** Your `pointer_to_node` function is too complex please change it with

```
Node* pointer_to_node(int index) {
    Node* tempPtr = firstptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
         tempPtr = tempPtr->nextptr;
    }
    return tempPtr;
}
```

And see if this will fix your problem. More lines of code very rarely means better programming skills, do not artificially try to increase their count.

Answer (score 0):

I think another possible issue here, aside from all the memory leaks and style issues which are already well documented, is that your code does not seem to handle the case of there only being one thing in the list.

If that happens, it will delete that node, but leave `firstptr` and `lastptr` pointing at random memory.

If your size_of_list() function is just counting nodes in the list, it will probably still think there are non-zero nodes remaining, and you might then attempt to remove or otherwise access another node.